# If two DOM codes exist, error comes out and the code won't run (but run smoothly if each is used separately)

Tags: javascript, css, dom, createelement

I just started learning how to code. I have been trying to crack this for almost 3 hours and it is almost 2 a.m but no results... I would really appreciate all the help I can get.

I am trying to write the code where every time a designated button is clicked, it would add a new item in CSS grid. I understand that evenlistener is needed, and that DOM is necessary.

I understand that if there is no item at all (dashboardQuantity == 0), the DOM code for to create the CSS grid and the first grid item will need to run. And if at least 1 CSS grid item exists, the DOM code will add new CSS grid items in front of the old ones.

**Oddly, both of the codes won't run properly together:**
1. If in the HTML file I created the CSS grid and first item, and then use DOM to add a new item in front of the old one, it works.

2. If I don't add the code for the grid and first item, and instead run the DOM code to add the CSS grid and first item, it works as well. This is the "if" section below.
3. But! If I don't write anything in HTML and wrote all the DOM code (for the grid, first item, and new items onwards), the code won't work at all. This is the "else if" section below.
4. Also, I can only add one item from DOM if the HTML code has CSS grid and first item. In other words, I can't add more than 2 items. This I really don't know why...

**The HTML code (the comment section is the CSS grid + first item):**

```
<body>
    <button id="createDashboardButton" 
            class="main-action-button create-dashboard-button"></button>
    <button id="rearrangeDashboardButton" 
            class="main-action-button rearrange-dashboard-button"></button>
    <button id="deleteDashboardButton" 
            class="main-action-button delete-dashboard-button"></button>
    <!-- 
    <div id = dashboard-grid class="dashboard-grid">
        <div class="dashboard-name">Dashboard 2</div>
    </div>
    -->
    <script src="dom.js"></script>
</body>
```

**As for the JS file (DOM):**

```
var dashboardQuantity = 0
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// First Dashboard Creation
var createFirstDashboardDiv = document.createElement("div");
createFirstDashboardDiv.id = "dashboard-grid";
createFirstDashboardDiv.className = "dashboard-grid";
var forFirstDashboardCreation = document.querySelector("#deleteDashboardButton");
var firstDashboard = document.querySelector("script");
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// For Dashboard Creation
var createDashboardDiv = document.createElement("div");
var createDashboardTextNode = document.createTextNode("Dashboard " + dashboardQuantity);
createDashboardDiv.id = "dashboard" + dashboardQuantity;
createDashboardDiv.className = "dashboard-name";
createDashboardDiv.appendChild(createDashboardTextNode);
var forDashboardCreation = document.querySelector("#dashboard-grid");
var oldDashboard = document.querySelector("body .dashboardName");
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// Functions
function createDashboard(){
    if (dashboardQuantity == 0){
        dashboardQuantity += 1;
        forFirstDashboardCreation.parentNode.insertBefore(createFirstDashboardDiv,
                                                          firstDashboard.nextSibling);
        document.getElementById("dashboard-grid").appendChild(createDashboardDiv);
    } else if (dashboardQuantity > 0){
        dashboardQuantity += 1;
        forDashboardCreation.insertBefore(createDashboardDiv,
                                          forDashboardCreation.firstChild);
    }
}
```

**For the clicking-the-button-to-activate-code:**

```
document.getElementById("createDashboardButton")
        .addEventListener("click", createDashboard);
```

I would really really appreciate the help...! Thank you in advance!

Comment: You create `#dashboard-grid` dynamically, then immediately after reference it. Performing an operation like this requires a listener and event delegation otherwise your script won't know it was added to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce what you are trying to do with what was provided. But to solve the issue you need to attach the click event listener to a static element so when the new elements are appended to the DOM they can be selected. This is called "event delegation."

```
<body>
  <div id="static-parent">
    <button id="createDashboardButton" class="main-action-button create-dashboard-button"></button>
    <button id="rearrangeDashboardButton" class="main-action-button rearrange-dashboard-button"></button>
    <button id="deleteDashboardButton" class="main-action-button delete-dashboard-button"></button>

    <script src="dom.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here I've attached to the parent as stated before and we only execute the function if the id we want is clicked.

```
var parent = document.getElementById("static-parent");

parent.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.id === "deleteDashboardButton") {
        createDashboard();
    }
});
```

One issue with your code, is you can't do...

```
var forDashboardCreation = document.querySelector("#dashboard-grid");
```

It won't exist in the DOM yet. You need to use the element you created until after it is appended. So you need to reference `createFirstDashboardDiv` directly instead of `forDashboardCreation`.